# How can generate an object, catching the user's id and put in my result?

Tags: javascript

i am building a structure, i am getting the value if exist the key in both objets, i have this arrays about users and i have another object about brands, but i want to match user's brand with brands

```js
let users = [{id:1,brand: 'RET'},{id:2,brand: 'CAT'}]
let brands = {TYS: 81,RET: 62,CAT: 90,NK:  87,}
for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(brands)){
    brands[key] = {
        value, exist: users.some(({brand})=>brand===key)
    }
}
console.log(brands)
```

but i want this result:

```
{
  "TYS": {
    "value": 81,
    "exist": false
  },
  "RET": {
    "id":1,
    "value": 62,
    "exist": true
  },
  "CAT": {
    "id":2,
    "value": 90,
    "exist": true
  },
  "NK": {
    "value": 87,
    "exist": false
  }
}
```

I want to grab the user id and put it in the result object, I don't want to do any more iterations.

Comment: You could save the id inside the callback function of the `some()` method. If the condition  `brand===key` is true, save the id in some variable and then at the end of the `for of` loop, check if the `id` variable is null or undefined - if its not, add the id in the result object

Comment: Also i suggest you to use the `map()` method to avoid mutating the `brands` object.

Comment: @Yousaf can you create your answer please

Comment: [Demo](https://jsbin.com/hecizohati/1/edit?js,console,output). Ideally, i think you should create a `Map` of the `users` so that you can easily find the user without needing to iterate over an array. Inside the `Map`, `brand` could be the key and the `id` or the whole user object could be the value.

Comment: @Yousaf exist can be true or false

Answer (score 0):

Key your array by brand so you construct an object with brand as a key, I think that will help you accesing values quickly and asking rapidly for an id without more iterations, you could try this:

```js
const users = [{id:1,brand: 'RET'},{id:2,brand: 'CAT'}];
let brands = {TYS: 81,RET: 62,CAT: 90,NK:  87,};

const brandUsers = users.reduce((acc, usr) => ({ ...acc, [usr.brand]: usr }), {});
console.log(brandUsers);


for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(brands)){
    const user = brandUsers[key];
    const baseValue = { value, exist: !!user }

    brands[key] = user?.id ? { id: user.id, ...baseValue } : baseValue;
}
console.log(brands)
```